# Correct data update architecture

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, database-design, cron, architecture

## The process

I update contents by several crons. Some crons update metadatas from different sources, some update prices from different sources, some push the contents to things like marketplaces.

Until now, each process adds a column on the content table, like "last_amazon_update" and stores a timestamp there. The crons then grabs the X oldest updated and updates them, and sets the timestamp to now, which puts it "at the end of the list".
Also, all new contents inserted have this column at null, and the cron grabs them also.

## The limitations

The main limitation is the quotas for the APIs I use : it's why I can't update all the contents all the time, or even get the datas from the APIs as soon as the content is created.
Secondly, I'm trying to be a little savvy on computing.

## The problem

I'm not fond of this way to store the updates info, as it interferes and overloads the content table itself. The only quality it has is that at every cron run, the contents to update are retrieved with the query to get what contents have to be updated (no join needed or whatsoever).

**The main blocker is all the weight and confusion these columns add to the actual data that serves the main purpose, store my book references and books in stock.**

I'm working in NodeJS with google cloud, firestore and postgre.

## Question

**What would be the best data storage architecture here ?**

For now, apart from putting these datas in a joined table instead of the content table itself, I have no idea. Maybe there's something using pub/sub and queues that I don't know of ?
I dream of a much more simple storage where, as an example, I would store only the id of the last updated content and could go up from there, or store only the contents that have to be updated...

Comment: What's your main blocker here? The API quotas or other limitation? Do you have 1 cron per content? or it's 1 cron per API?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I have one cron per API but I can refactor everything if needed there.

Comment: In your question, what exactly is "here", after & before all that content? Please ask 1 specific researched/(re)searchable non-duplicate question. Give all & only relevant context necessary to ask it.
[Why is asking a question on "best practice" a bad thing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/142353/266284) 
[Strategy for “Which is better” questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204461)
 PS Please clarify via edits, not comments. [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 1):

Yeah overloading your content table with stuff related to update info isn't so great in my opinion, it will have a bit of impacts during get / insert / update.

Having a separate table, as you mentioned is, in my opinion, the goto way, something like `ContentUpdate`, with a few columns like `content_id`, `update_provider`, `update_timestamp`  to help you join & sort as needed.

With that table, you should be able to perform queries for your provider as needed, and add / remove data provider like you want. And it would open up a lot of new possibility for monitoring / debugging data providers (like saving the status of the update, the duration taken by the request, adding a batch id and checking how much data where processed during that batch etc)

Also, if you know in advance the api rate limits, you can perform paginated queries with some helpers (like [this one](https://github.com/charlie-hadden/kysely-paginate) for kysely, or a classic `Cursor` with node-postgres), it would maybe help you gain a bit in term of perf / database load.

With that design, it's opening up a new question, how to handle freshly inserted content initial update? I think you got two options:

- During batch, complexify a bit the sql query to select every content that isn't present in that new `ContentUpdate` table, and add after the remaining content based on the `update_timestamp`.
- During content creation, insert some fake data inside `ContentUpdate` table, and so you can still have a simple query, but you would have non realistic data inside that table.